# How to quickly check if an array is coprime using MATLAB

Tags: algorithm, matlab, primes, discrete-mathematics, prime-factoring

I would like to write a function in MATLAB that can quickly determine whether an array is coprime. Formally, we say that an N x 1 array `x` is coprime if the largest positive integer that divides all N elements is 1 (see here for a more extensive [definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Coprime_integers#Coprimality_in_sets)).

The function that I have in mind should input an array of integers `x`, and output `true` if x is coprime. Some examples:

```
%example
x = [6,10,15];
iscoprime(x)
> true

%counter-example
x = 2*[1,2,3];
iscoprime(x)
> false
```

---

**Answer** The current best attempt at this is:

```
function value = iscoprime(x)

%remove 0 and take absolute value
x = abs(x(x==0));
nx = length(x);

%return true if all original entries = 0
if nx == 0, value = true;

%return false if x only contains 1 value and it is not 1
elseif nx == 1 & x~=1, value = false;

%return true if x contains a 1 (easy way to tell if x is coprime)
elseif any(x==1), value = true;

%check if x is coprime (based on Yasen's answer)
else

    v = x(1);
    for i = 2:nx
        v = gcd(v,x(i));
        if (v == 1), 
            value = true;
            break
        end
    end
    value = false;

end
end
```

Can anyone suggest a faster method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [the built in MATLAB function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/gcd.html) for finding the Greatest Common Divisor (GCD) for every two consecutive numbers in the array and accumulate the result in some variable GCD. If GCD = 1, then the numbers are coprime. Otherwise, they are not coprime and GCD is their common factor.

Here is the code:

```
function GCD = iscoprime(x) % assuming x is an array, 
    GCD = x(1);             % returning greatest common divisor for the array
    for i=1:size(x, 2)
        GCD = gcd(GCD, x(i));
    end
end
```

Comment: Sorry this is not true. Take x = [6, 10, 15]. Here x is coprime, but gcd(6,10) = 2, gcd(6,15) = 3, and gcd(10,15) = 5.

Comment: I meant to accumulate this value in GCD. For your example, GCD=6 at start. Then GCD = gcd(GCD=6, 10) = 2. After that, GCD = gcd(GCD=2, 15) = 1. So the numbers are coprime. I will add some source code when I'm ready with testing :)

Comment: Thank you! I went ahead and implemented it. Considerably faster than the previous case :-)